# Oracle SQL: Check if entry exists and return if it DOESN'T

Tags: sql, oracle, join, subquery, left-join

I want to check if an entry exists in one table based on a value from a 2nd table, but if it DOESN'T exist then select the value from the 2nd table.

To explain, I have a table called `devices` and a table called `tests`. Each device in `devices` has a unique identifier (an integer). Each test in `tests` references the unique identifier of the device that the test was run on. Therefore, every `test` is associated with a `device`. However, not every `device` has been tested. Moreover, multiple tests could have been run on a single device.

So what I want to `SELECT` is all entries in `devices` that are NOT referenced by at least one entry in `tests`.

Answer (score 4):

> So what I want to SELECT is all entries in devices that are NOT referenced by at least one entry in tests.

Assuming the following data structures:

```
devices(id)
tests(id, device_id)
```

You could use `not exists`:

```
select d.*
from devices
where not exists (
    select 1
    from tests t
    where t.device_id = d.id
)
```

Or a left join antipattern:

```
select d.*
from devices d
left join tests t on t.device_id = d.id
where t.id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `NOT IN` to achieve your desired result (assuming `id` as the unique identifier in `devices`, `device_id` as the foreign key to `devices.id` within `tests`, and `tests.device_id` has a `NOT NULL` attribute:

```
SELECT *
FROM devices
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT device_id
    FROM tests
);
```

This should work across most major RDBMS'; since you haven't specified which one you're using, your mileage may vary.

Comment: IN/NOT IN/EXISTS subqueries are already implicitly distinct (in Oracle at least).

Comment: @WilliamRobertson thanks. This answer was made before the Oracle title/tag was added. I will leave the answer as-is for the time being,

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, that worked. I'll admit, I changed the names of my tables above to make it easier to ask the question, but here's what I concluded with and it's working correctly:

```
SELECT DEVICE.ID
FROM DEVICE
WHERE DEVICE.ID NOT IN (
SELECT TEST.DEVICEID FROM TEST WHERE TEST.DEVICEID=DEVICE.ID)
ORDER BY DEVICE.ID
```

Simple in the end. Can't tell I'm a beginner at SQL, can you? :)

Comment: I would adocate against using `NOT IN`, since it can lead to unexpected behaviors when dealing with `NULL`s.